# Can anyone gives me an example of $V$ such that there exists at least one pair of elements $ a,c(\neq 0 ,1) \in D$ such that $V(a) > V(ac)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

$D$ is an Integral Domain.

$V$ only satisfies the first Euclidean property, i.e. for all $\,a,b\in D\,$ if $\,b\neq 0\,$ then there are $\,q,r\in D\,$ such that $\, a = qb +r\,$ with either $r=0$ or $\, V(r) < V(b),\,$ where $V$ maps $D$ into  (well-ordered)  $\,\Bbb N$.
?
Can anyone gives me an example of $V$ such that there exists at least one  pair of elements $ a,c(\neq 0 ,1) \in D$ such that $V(a) > V(ac)$?

I have been really trying hard to construct one. But I can't.

Comment: I have edited the question..@HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let $D=\Bbb Q[X]$ and
$$ V(f)=\begin{cases}
2\deg f&\forall x\gg 0\colon f(x)>0 \\
2\deg f+1&\forall x\gg 0\colon f(x)<0 \\
\text{whatever}&f=0\end{cases}$$

For $a,b\ne0$, we can find by polynomial division $q,r$ with $a=qb+r$ and either $r=0$ or $\deg r<\deg b$, in which case also have $V(r)<V(b)$.
Thus the desired conditins hold.
Now let $a=c=-1$ and note that $V(a)=1$, $V(ac)=0$.

Comment: Can you please make some small edit in your answer so that I can upvote?@HagenvonEitzen